# Dynamic loading java classes in terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, classloader

The application is modular plug-in architecture. That is, while the work is done dynamically load classes. For this purpose a custom class loader extends ClassLoader.

The essence of the problem is that in Eclipse application runs, while in terminal (ubuntu) using the following line of code (where the Catalog "m /" indicates the location of the modules * .class):

```
java -jar ModularApp.jar m/
```

I get the following message:

> 10:07:24,085 DEBUG main CModuleLoader:findClass:39 - Run of the System Classloader.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ru/intetech/module/CModule
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643) at
>   ru.intetech.moduleloader.CModuleLoader.findClass(CModuleLoader.java:35)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) at
>   ru.intetech.modularApp.Main.main(Main.java:42) ... 5 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.intetech.module.CModule at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531) at
>   ru.intetech.moduleloader.CModuleLoader.findClass(CModuleLoader.java:40)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ... 12 more

Here's a snippet of code, the user class loader (extending ClassLoader), where there is an error:

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    try
    {
        byte b[]=getClassAsBytes(m_pathToBin+className+".class");
        return (defineClass(className, b, 0, b.length));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        m_log.debug("Run of the System Classloader.");
        return (super.findClass(className));
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        m_log.debug("Run of the Bootstrap.");
        return (super.findClass(className));
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

P.S. Loader implemented on the basis of this article:
http://sysmagazine.com/posts/104229/

Answer (score 0):

Look: The stack trace shows the message "Run of the System Classloader", which proves that the first catch was executed. This was caused by a FileNotFoundException, which clearly occurred in the getClassAsBytes method: This is what you must investigate: Find out what file you are trying to read (put a trace showing the the *absolute* path), and why that file does not exist.

(Eventually, that catch block tries to load the required class by the system classloader, which has no acces to that class, and so, it throws the ClassNotFoundException).

Comment: I did as you advised.

Comment: **Added a line logging.**
`//...
m_log.debug("#Path: "+m_pathToBin+className+".class");
   byte b[]=getClassAsBytes(m_pathToBin+className+".class");
//...`

**Now I get the message:**
_15:55:39,634 DEBUG main Main:main:36 - Load file: CModulePrinter2.class
15:55:39,637 DEBUG main CModuleLoader:findClass:34 - #Path: m/CModulePrinter2.class
15:55:39,637 DEBUG main CModuleLoader:findClass:34 - #Path: m/ru.intetech.module.CModule.class
15:55:39,638 DEBUG main CModuleLoader:findClass:40 - Run of the System Classloader._
**CModulePrinter imports class CModule that attempts to load the ClassLoader.**

Comment: Reading this log, I can see you forgot _the package part_ in the full path: Surely your .class file is in m/ru/intetech/module/CModulePrinter2.class

Comment: I put this class, nothing has changed.

You probably had in mind:
m/ru/intetech/module/CModule.class

Comment: It's quite simple: Log the _absolute path_ where the method getClassAsBytes is trying to read a file, and check if that path corresponds to your expected .class file. The root cause of it all is that FileNotFoundException.